# Dji Tello EDU | Swarm with Video

Tags: python, dji-sdk, tello-drone

I'm new into this and i want to control 2 Tello EDUs in swarm. I tried couple of things that worked for one not in swarm but crashed in swarm (i think I did something in bad way) and I can't figure out Video Stream in swarm.
I would be thankful for help with it.

I am using DJITelloPy library from [GitHub](https://github.com/damiafuentes/DJITelloPy).
Controlling for one drone I did from this [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/LmEcyQnfpDA?t=2194). I also tried control in example of DJITelloPy but also doesn't work.

```
from djitellopy import TelloSwarm
import cv2

swarm = TelloSwarm.fromIps([
    "10.0.0.125",
    "10.0.0.126"
])

swarm.connect()
for tello in swarm:
        print(tello.get_battery())

swarm.streamon()

while True:
    img = {}
    for tello in swarm:
        img[i] = tello.get_frame_read().frame

    
    for i in img:
        img[i] = cv2.resize(img[i], (360, 240))
        cv2.imshow("Image", img[i])
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

This should just connect to them on the network (by their IPs) and run Image capture. I don't think it is the right way. Can someone help me? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this won't work.

After setting every Tello in station mode with `ap ssid pass` there is no image and video capturing possible any more.

This is a technical limitation of the Tello we all hope will be resolved someday.

Please see https://github.com/dji-sdk/Tello-Python/issues/25

Comment: don't believe what DJI says. I and my student made it work as shown in the youtube channel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24dJXXGyvAI&ab_channel=JiaNingSoh.  You may refer to this technical report for details. https://github.com/snakehaihai/Tello_formation_and_visual_control/blob/master/Technical%20Report.pdf  . The key command and instructions are all in the appendix section

Comment: Yes, video feed only works when drone is in access point only and not when in station mode, as you explain in your video. Your video is very well done. I like your solution with the Raspberry PIs, but rather prefer Ryze to come up with a solution native to the Tello that does not require any additional hardware.

Comment: To be honest, i I talked to Ryze and DJI and asked for a solution half year ago. But they say, you have to explore yourself :) .  Seems developer care is not their concern

Answer (score 0):

Tello AP mode by default can not run in a swarm manner. Tello Station mode only allows you to control drone position, the image feed are all crash at port 11111 which makes the image unavailable in this case.

If you are trying to control multiple drones with Computer vision (CV) based method, The answer is AP mode with IPforwarding / Prerouting. It's slightly more complicated and requires tons of hands-on trial and error.

Me and my student made it work as shown on the youtube channel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24dJXXGyvAI&ab_channel=JiaNingSoh.

[image]
[image]

You may refer to this technical report for details. https://github.com/snakehaihai/Tello_formation_and_visual_control/blob/master/Technical%20Report.pdf  .
The key command and instructions are all in the appendix section

[image]
Sample applications
[image]
Sample commands

My FYP student has layout most of the key works such as making all of them running in a centralized swarm manner with DJI internal position control. I handle most of the CV and SLAM part

I`m still working on putting down the code and instructions in the same GitHub space to make it easy for people to use it. But I do also have many other project work. Teaching is only a small part of the job. So, it might take a little bit longer time :) cheers

Regards

Dr. Yuan Shenghai